# Unsupported type for timedelta days, - when trying to make an extended version of the Timedelta-class

Tags: python, datetime

I'm quite new to OOP, - so this might be a silly question. Be gentle, please...

I'm want to make a class just like the `datetime.timedelta`-class, but with a few modifications (such as: if there's more than 1 days worth of time, then it'll still output it as hours and minutes; and that seconds are never printed).

My plan was to take a timedelta-object as input into the class that also extends the `datetime.timedelta`-class - but that's giving me problems. Here's my code:

```
class my_own_timedelta_class(datetime.timedelta):

  def __init__(self, timedelta_object):
    self.foo = 'bar' # not important.

test_duration = datetime.timedelta(days=3, hours=5, minutes=20, seconds=7)
testing = my_own_timedelta_class(test_duration)
```

And it's giving me this error:

```
unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.timedelta
```

Why do I get that error? All I'm doing is passing a `timedelta_object` to the constructor - I don't even do anything with it, and it still complains!?

I also thought about just passing the seconds to `my_own_timedelta_class`, - but I figured that it would be 'cleaner' to pass the entire object.

And are there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently trying to do both [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)):

```
class my_own_timedelta_class(datetime.timedelta)
```

and [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition):

```
def __init__(self, timedelta_object):
```

It's like saying "My new class **is** a car, but it also **contains** a car". Choose one or the other; it doesn't make sense to do both.

In this particular case I would recommend doing composition, because subclassing `timedelta` can be troublesome. Just remove the inheritance from `timedelta` and you're good to go:

```
class my_own_timedelta_class:
    def __init__(self, timedelta_object):
        self.delta= timedelta_object
        self.foo = 'bar' # not important.
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for your answer. That works. Can I get you to elaborate, why that provokes Python to throw the error: `unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.timedelta` ? For instance... Is it because 'things that are cars, can't contain cars' or because 'things that contain cars, can't be cars'. I hope this additional question makes sense.